# How do I pass a function variable to Dart Colors

Tags: function, dart

I want to create a dart function that will build a that will play a note but use vars in the function callout to set the key color. Below is my shot but it generates the exception:

*:18:21: Error: Getter not found: '$kcolor'.
color: Colors.$kcolor,*
^^^^^^^

```
  FlatButton buildKey({int notenum, String kcolor, double hedgeInset, String ttitle}) {
onPressed() {playSound(notenum);}
child: Card(
  color: Colors.kcolor,
  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0,
      horizontal: hedgeInset),
  child: ListTile(
    title: Text(
      ttitle,
    )
  )

);
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to look up a static member of `Color` given a string containing its name.

Dart does not support that. Using a run-time `String` (or `Symbol`) to refer to a source name is reflection. You can only do that using the reflection library `dart:mirrors`, and Flutter does not provide that library (nor does most other Dart platforms).

If you need to translate a string into a color, then you need to build a translation table first. Something like:

```dart
const colorMap = {
  "accents": Colors.accents,
  "amber": Colors.amber,
  "amberAccent": Colors.amberAccent,
  "black": Colors.black,
  "black12": Colors.black12,
  "black26": Colors.black26,
  "black38": Colors.black38,
  "black45": Colors.black45,
  "black54": Colors.black54,
  "black87": Colors.black87,
  "blue": Colors.blue,
  "blueAccent": Colors.blueAccent,
  "blueGrey": Colors.blueGrey,
  "brown": Colors.brown,
  "cyan": Colors.cyan,
  "cyanAccent": Colors.cyanAccent,
  "deepOrange": Colors.deepOrange,
  "deepOrangeAccent": Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
  "deepPurple": Colors.deepPurple,
  "deepPurpleAccent": Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
  "green": Colors.green,
  "greenAccent": Colors.greenAccent,
  "grey": Colors.grey,
  "indigo": Colors.indigo,
  "indigoAccent": Colors.indigoAccent,
  "lightBlue": Colors.lightBlue,
  "lightBlueAccent": Colors.lightBlueAccent,
  "lightGreen": Colors.lightGreen,
  "lightGreenAccent": Colors.lightGreenAccent,
  "lime": Colors.lime,
  "limeAccent": Colors.limeAccent,
  "orange": Colors.orange,
  "orangeAccent": Colors.orangeAccent,
  "pink": Colors.pink,
  "pinkAccent": Colors.pinkAccent,
  "primaries": Colors.primaries,
  "purple": Colors.purple,
  "purpleAccent": Colors.purpleAccent,
  "red": Colors.red,
  "redAccent": Colors.redAccent,
  "teal": Colors.teal,
  "tealAccent": Colors.tealAccent,
  "transparent": Colors.transparent,
  "white": Colors.white,
  "white10": Colors.white10,
  "white12": Colors.white12,
  "white24": Colors.white24,
  "white30": Colors.white30,
  "white38": Colors.white38,
  "white54": Colors.white54,
  "white60": Colors.white60,
  "white70": Colors.white70,
  "yellow": Colors.yellow,
  "yellowAccent": Colors.yellowAccent,
};
```

Then you can write:

```dart
  colorMap[kcolor]
```

Comment: To my eye, this looks a lot like a python dict.

Comment: Python dictionaries *are* maps, so that's unsurprising. It also looks identical to a JavaScript object, and similar to a Perl hash, a Groovy map or a Swift dictionary. Most modern languages have some key/value collection literal.

Answer (score 0):

Dart Color always has int value, you can use it like this `Colors.redAccent.value`.
And with this attribute you can modify your function like this.

```
FlatButton buildKey({int notenum, int kcolor, double hedgeInset, String ttitle}) {
onPressed() {playSound(notenum);}
child: Card(
  color: Color(kcolor),//you can turn value of color to back to system color like this
  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0,
      horizontal: hedgeInset),
  child: ListTile(
    title: Text(
      ttitle,
    )
  )
);
```